# Force an 'enter' event inside a form on a mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, form-submit, enter

I have a following page structure. There's a contact form. Inside that form there is a search field. User types a value into the input field, clicks 'search' button (or hits enter key), and selects one of the results. That result is getting submitted with the main contact form.

I initially decided not to play with the idea of nested forms and created two behaviors for the input search fields - on button click and on enter press. On both occasions jquery picks up the value from input and passes to search logic.

Button click works on both desktop and mobile. Enter however works fine only on desktop. What happens on mobile (iOS and Android) is that while typing a value inside the search input field, the virtual keyboard appearing on mobile screen displays 'next/search' button, not the 'enter/go' button. As a result, when value is typed in and user touches the button, cursor moves to the next field instead of triggering 'enter' event.

The markup for a search field looks like this

```
<input type="text" name="x"><button value="search">Search</button>
```

The question then is, how to force mobile OS to display 'enter' key on the keyboard for that input field. Or, if that is not possible (which I assume may be the case), how to modify the construct of the entire form to handle this (using jquery)?

Comment: You should use a `type="search"` input.

Comment: wow, that was easy :) Thanks alex